# How to parse the month from a list of strings that contain dates and other strings inside the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of lists

```
list1 = [['0', '2015-12-27', '64236.62'], 
         ['1', '2015-12-12', '65236.12'], 
         ... ]
```

This list contains data from 2015 to 2018
how to figure out the value for each month?
So, I would like to create a dictionary with data for each month for a certain year.

I have tried like this:

```
import re
years_month_count = {}
for i in list1:
    match = re.search("[2][0][1][5-8]-[0-9][0-9]", i[1])
    if match not in years_month_count:
        years_month_count[match] = 0
    else:
        years_month_count[match] += float(i[2])
```

Comment: Why use a regular expression at all. `m = i[1].split("-")[1]`

Comment: Also, look at `collections.defaultdict` -- very handy for when you want a dictionary to have an initial value for a new key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), you can do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [['0', '2015-12-27', '64236.62'], 
         ['1', '2015-11-12', '65236.12'], 
         ['2', '2015-12-27', '64236.62']]

d = defaultdict(float)
for x in list1:
    d[x[1].rsplit('-', 1)[0]] += float(x[2])
```

The output will be a `dict` like:

```
{'2015-12': 128473.24, '2015-11': 65236.12}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `else` clause, since you always want to add the value, even for the first item of a month.

Also, you don't need a regular expression. If all the datestamps are well formed, you you can simply use string slicing.

```
years_month_count = {}

for _, date, value in list1:
    month = date[:7]
    years_month_count[month] = float(value) + years_month_count.get(month, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create your dictionary and initialize it to 0

   ```
   d = {i:0 for i in range(1,13)}
   ```
2. loop through your list, split string to get month, and add value to dictionary.

   ```
   for l in list1:
       splt = l[1].split("-")
       d[int(splt[1])] += float(l[2])
   ```